# Mongo document to poco error on DateTime

Tags: c#, mongodb

My document looks like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58064346e74f22124037a607"),
    "Date" : ISODate("2016-10-18T15:44:01.083Z")
}
```

My poco looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ObjectId _id;
    Public BsonDateTime Date;
}
```

When I read the document using JsonConvert I am getting an error when it tries to serialize the Date type.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use BsonAttributes to set the MongoDb Bson representation. Also I always use string to represent an ObjectId in my DTOs and use the attribute as shown below to have it serialize/deserialize correctly

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

public class MyClass
{  
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you're using BsonDateTime? If you deseralizing the Bson in to a poco just use a DateTime:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ObjectId _id;
    Public DateTime Date;
}
```